# Generics Java Interface

Tags: java, generics

I need this code to accept all numbers: Stations should be able to be put in as Integers, Doubles, or Float.  My question is specifically regarding the Interface.  Am I using generics properly here?  Should I replace all instances of "Double" with "T"?

Cheers and thanks.

```
    public class generics {

        public class WrongStation extends Exception  {
              public WrongStation () { super(); }
              public WrongStation (String message) { super(message); }
              public WrongStation (String message, Throwable cause) { super(message, cause); }
              public WrongStation (Throwable cause) { super(cause); }
        }

        interface Changeable <T> extends Collection <T> {
            void setChannel(Number channelNumber) throws wrongStation;
            Number  getChannel();
            Number getMinChannel();
            Number getMaxChannel();
            Number getChannelIncrement();
        }
```

Does the code above look correct in terms of using generics?  I want the program to run regardless if the user enters an Interger, Double, or Float.  Here is the rest of the program:

```
class FMRadio implements Changeable {
            double channel = 88.1;

            public void setChannel(Number newChannel) {
                System.out.println("HAM Radio channel set to: " + newChannel);
                channel (Double) = (Double)newChannel; 
            }

            public T getChannel() {
                return channel;
            }

            public Double getMinChannel() {
                return 88.1;
            }

            public Double getMaxChannel() {
                return 107.9;
            }

            public Double getChannelIncrement() {
                return 0.2;
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEmpty() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean contains(Object o) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Iterator iterator() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Object[] toArray() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Object[] toArray(Object[] a) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean add(Object e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean remove(Object o) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean containsAll(Collection c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean addAll(Collection c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean removeAll(Collection c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean retainAll(Collection c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void clear() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }

        public static class HamRadio {
            public void main(String[] args) {
                HamRadio myRadio = new HamRadio();

                myRadio.setChannel(133.9);
                myRadio.setChannel(300);


            }
        }}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is your issue?

Comment: Please follow Java conventions and name classes starting with an uppercase letter; it makes your code easier to read. Also, exception classes should generally end with `Exception` and should inherit the best available superclass: `WrongStationException extends IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: I want the code to work, regardless if an int, double, float, ect is entered.

Comment: remmember that generics work with classes, not primitive types, so you will have to use the classes that encapsulate those primitive types: `Integer`, `Double`, etc. Other than that, I think this question is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user2644085 You don't want generics in that case, since you're just dealing with basic numbers all the way around. First, you probably don't really want to support integral types, since FM frequencies always have a decimal component (and in the US, it's always odd, so the frequency in MHz is never an integer). Second, it's okay to pass a `float` into a `double`, so someone who's using a `float` for some reason can pass it to `setChannel` with no problems.

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be enough for accepting any type of numbers :

```
  interface Changeable {
            void setChannel(Number channelNumber) throws wrongStation;
            Number  getChannel();
            Number getMinChannel();
            Number getMaxChannel();
            Number getChannelIncrement();
        }
```

usage

```
 class Radio implement Changeble{
```

or using generics and more precision

```
interface Changeable <T extends Number> {
            void setChannel(T channelNumber) throws wrongStation;
            T getChannel();
            T getMinChannel();
            T getMaxChannel();
            T getChannelIncrement();
        }
```

usage

```
class Radio implement Changeble{
```

or

```
 class Radio implement Changeble<Double>{
```

or

```
class Radio implement Changeble<Integer>{
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface declaration `Changeable` looks correct.  However, you're using the raw form of your interface when implementing it with `FMRadio`.  You'll want something like

```
class FMRadio implements Changeable<Double> {
```

Here, `Double` could be whatever you intend to be in your `Collection`.  Or you could make `FMRadio` itself generic:

```
class FMRadio<E> implements Changeable<E> {
```

Either way, you will need to change your method signatures to use the generic type parameter where it's needed in the `Collection` interface: `add` and `addAll`.